# How to call lightbox from outstanding link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, lightbox2

Does somebody know, how to call a lightbox from an custom link?

Example:

```
$('#price1 a').lightBox(); //in the header
```

Now I want to click a custom link somewhere on the page.

```
<a href="#" class="price1">Link to lightBox</a>
```

And images in a div (until link clicked they are not visible)

```
<div id="price1" style="display: none;">
    <a href="../images/img1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="../images/img2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="../images/img3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Could somebody please help.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [jQuery events binding](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind):

```
$(".price1").bind("click", function() {
    $("#price1 a:first").click();
};
```

This way, when you click on link with class "price1", jQuery will emulate clicking on first link in div with id "price1".

Comment: where should past this code? in the header? It doesn't work and no errors.

Comment: In the header. Try pasting it just after "...lightbox();" line.

Comment: OK, sorry for my mistake. See my edit, the thing is you have to click on one of the links in div "#price1" (I choose first one with selector "a:first"), not just on the div.